# Behaviour of the set_index method in Dask using a column with duplicates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a question regarding the `set_index()` method in Dask using a single column with duplicates. I know that there is some change of order since duplicated indexes (if there’re any) are “grouped” within the same partition in the resulting DataFrame. In fact, I’m doing this because I’m using the `map_partitions()` method to keep the last of those duplicates.

My doubt is whether the `set_index()` method always keeps the same order of rows with a duplicated index within the “group”.

Comment: From my experience, the order is retained. However, I'd love to see a more involved answer.

Comment: @Dahn Yes, I've noticed the same so far. But I haven't found a confirmation in the documentation or elsewhere. Thanks for the reply tho.

Comment: @Dahn do you have a minimal code example that would help us reproduce and diagnose your problem?

Comment: @rrpelgrim perhaps you meant to direct the comment at OP? No problem on my side, just saying that anecdotally the order always seemed to be retained.

Comment: @Dahn - you're right, sorry about that. Comment above meant for OP